# Getting error while writing bytes to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, file-writing, customtkinter

I am working on a tkinter projects which save encrypted passwords. I am writing key to this path: `C:\Users\<usrname>\.PassManager\PassManager.key`.

It was working fine, all of sudden I do not what happened I am getting this error. While writing I have mentioned to write **bytes** to file. It doesn't seems working.

**Understanding:**

Error: `'bool' object`

`self.key_path()` is not a boolean variable?

What is the cause of this problem?

**Error:**

```
<class 'bytes'>
b'Oy21Nnu_A0f7xFuS-7pnFegt5Dj0ks6n4_ksOPzlYck=' #<-------Writing this key

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\rohit\Desktop\Password Manager\app.py", line 559, in <module>
    app = App()
          ^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\rohit\Desktop\Password Manager\app.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.b64key = self.key()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\rohit\Desktop\Password Manager\app.py", line 522, in key
    with open(self.key_path, "wb") as file:
TypeError: 'bool' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

**Code:**

```
class App(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = True

        self.db_path = self.get_db_path()
        self.key_path = self.get_key_path()

        # Writing up db and key files
        self.dirFile_setup()


        # Secret key
        self.b64key = self.key()

# --------------- Code -------------------------

    def key():
        if path.exists(self.key_path) and stat(self.key_path).st_size == 0:
        key_ = Fernet.generate_key()
        print(type(key_))

        with open(self.key_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(key_)
            file.close()
        return key_
            
        else:# Opening exist file
            with open(self.key_path, "r") as file:
               return file.readlines()[0]
```

Comment: Doesn't do the error tell you exactly what is wrong ? Have you confirmed ?

Comment: Yes `self.key_path` is variable

Comment: You can checkout code

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: your code has wrong indentations - so it is useless.

Comment: I can't create code which would generate `TypeError: 'bool' object does not support the context manager protocol`. Better create `minimal working code` which we could simply copy and run it - to test problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you've overridden/shadowed the built-in *open* function with some callable that returns either True or False

Here are some examples that would lead to the exception you're observing:

```
# 1st possibility
def open():
    return True

# 2nd possibility
open = lambda: False

# 3rd possibility
def banana():
    return True

open = banana

# Then...
with open() as _:
    ...

...leads to...

TypeError: 'bool' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

Comment: Just to note, it might also be in the form `open = lambda path: True` instead of the function definition

Comment: Let me check it out

Comment: You were right as `from webbrowser import open`. This import statement was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When writing bytes to a file in Python, it's important to ensure that the file is opened in binary mode and that the data being written is in bytes format.
here the code how it is done--

```py
file_path = r'C:\Users\<usrname>\.PassManager\PassManager.key'
data_to_write = b'your_bytes_data_here'

try:
   
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
       
        file.write(data_to_write)
        print("Bytes have been successfully written to the file.")
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred while writing bytes to the file:", e)
```

Comment: This isn't going to solve OP's actual problem which is: `TypeError: 'bool' object does not support the context manager protocol`